# Nested Map or multi-key example Chronicle Map

Tags: multimap, chronicle-map, multikey

I have a use case where I want to create a co-occurrence matrix. Essentially it is going to be something like `Map<String, Map<String, Long>>`. I wish to use Chronicle-Map for this task.

I checked [Multimaps in ChronicleMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36483569/multimaps-in-chroniclemap) and https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map/issues/100. However, I am unable to follow the discussion to make a suitable change.

It would be also okay to have it like a multi-key like `Map<String, String, Long>` . I looked up the graph example of add and remove edge (in chronicle-map tutorial) which was again too detailed and complicated for me to adapt to my setting.

The way this will be used is to query:

1. Getting the long value for a very specific combination if key1 and key2.
2. For a specific key1 return all the key2 along with their respective long value.

Can someone please advise and provide a simple working example.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a `MapMarshaller` based on the source of [`SetMarshaller`](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map/blob/master/src/main/java/net/openhft/chronicle/hash/serialization/SetMarshaller.java) (yes, it's going to be even more complicated).  Or use a `Pair<String, String>` as a key.